# does cpu reorder instructions that are dependent on each other?

Tags: c++, cpu, barrier

I know that CPU can reorder instructions like

```
load A
load B
```

but will CPU reorder the following code? (in other words, will a second thread running on another core see the result in reverse order?)

```
some_array[array_index] = new_value;
++array_index;
```

I'm guessing it will **NEVER** because the second line is dependent on the first line. Am I right?

Comment: Answer: **No**. See [C++ Sequencing Guarantees](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

Comment: @iBug -- the OP asked 3 distinct questions. Can you clarify which one you are answering with "No". Thanks.

Comment: The CPU will not screw up your program. The compiler has a responsibility to make sure your program runs as written (undefined behavior not withstanding).

Comment: @MFisherKDX all of them :)

Comment: @Galik If you rely on behavior not guaranteed (what this question specifically asks about) then the CPU may very well screw up your program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, you're wrong.

The compiler and CPU are entirely free to optimize and re-order the code so long as the result is the same for any behavior that is guaranteed. That other threads will see the modifications in any particular order is not guaranteed. So, for example, the CPU and compiler are free to implement the code the same as this code:

```
++array_index;
some_array[array_index - 1] = new_value;
```

Or even:

```
tmp = array_index;
++array_index;
some_array[tmp] = new_value;
```

Since no guarantees are violated, the compiler and CPU are free to make these optimizations. That's a good thing because they may make the code significantly faster.

If you need more guarantees, you can use the appropriate tools (locks, barriers, atomics, whatever) to get them. But there's no reason code that doesn't care about this stuff should be denied optimizations like this.

Here's where you went wrong:

> I'm guessing it will NEVER because the second line is dependent on the first line. Am I right?

Only if neither the CPU nor the compiler can figure out the dependency and untangle it. But that's trivially obvious here. With the dependency figured out, they can be performed in either order, and compilers and CPUs do in fact figure out these kinds of dependencies (and even more complicated ones besides) because our software would be *much* slower if they didn't.

But even if the dependency was irrevocable, that wouldn't require the actual writes to be made visible to other threads in any particular order. They could sit in the CPU's write posting buffers and be executed in any order. And the other thread might re-order the reads too, with the CPU doing read ahead.

Comment: How does adding a memory barrier change the guarantees?

Comment: @MFisherKDX It depends on the [specifics of the barrier and the semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) the particular platform provides. But there are platforms that permit you to put a barrier instruction between the two lines of code that prevent specific optimizations -- for example, there are barriers that prevent any stores after the barrier from becoming visible until all stores before the barrier are guaranteed visible to other threads. (If you think about it, you need such barriers when implementing things like locks, since locks don't know what they lock.)

Comment: You wouldn't believe how many times I've seen lockless multi-threaded production code (ie: no synchronization semantics) where the correctness in one thread relied on the relative ordering of two sequential statements in another. I think this is very misunderstood subject. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I've seen a lot of that code break on newer CPUs that have more aggressive re-ordering. The x86 CPU family has a lot of heavy wizardry designed to detect code that relies on these kinds of things and make it work -- for example, pinning speculative fetches to cache lines. This was needed to make heaps of old, buggy Windows code work as CPUs became more concurrent. Sadly, it has produced a generation of programmers who assume they can rely on stuff that happened to work when they tested it.